# PHP: CSV import into MYSQL is always less than the actual amount of rows in the CSV file?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

This is a very strange issue that I have and I don't understand what's causing it.

Basically, the issue is that I have a simple upload function in my PHP that uploads a CSV file and then imports each row into the MYSQL database.

Now, the issue is that I have around `200+` rows in my CSV file but when i upload and import it into the MYSQL using my PHP page, I only get around `158 of them imported` and I don't get any errors at all either so i don't understand what's causing this.

I have another CSV file that has around `300+ rows` in it and when I upload/import this CSV file, i get around `270 rows imported` into MYSQL.

This is like the import function is always short a few rows and I don't understand it at all.

This is my PHP import code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if (isset($_POST['UP'])) { 

include "config/connect.php";

$imp= $_FILES["csv"]["name"];                                               
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"],"imports/$imp"); 



// path where your CSV file is located
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
define('CSV_PATH','');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "imports/".$imp.""; 
$i = 0;

set_time_limit(10000);


$fp = fopen("imports/".$imp."", "r");

while( !feof($fp) ) {
  if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '"')) {
     continue;
  }
    $sql0 = "INSERT INTO `myTable`(`column1`) VALUES('".$line[0]."')";
    $query0 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql0);

}

fclose($fp);

    printf("<script>location.href='mypage.php'</script>");
    exit();
}
```

Using direct import into MYSQL is out of question due to security issues/hole..

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when I debug code, I always use echo to find out whether or not a part of the code was executed... example, above the `continue;` in your code, if I found out that it was not executing the mysqli_query, then I'd place `echo "continuing";`... just to see if the while loop continued without executing the query. If it does not echo out "continuing", then try using `mysqli_error();`

Comment: I should follow Hallur advice. Also, replace this `fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '"')` with `fgetcsv($fp)` and see what happen.

Comment: Could you check if the file is imported fully? also could you also try printing a single column per row in a loop without inserting it into database? and if the loop reaches till the last row? My possible guess is that you are exceeding the maximum upload size of the file hence some part is clipped??

Comment: You may be running into quoting issues. You can bypass that by using prepared statements and `bind_param`. Otherwise, check for errors on each insert, and echo if there is an error.

Comment: Do the missing rows have anything in common, e.g. complex quoting, or more than your limit of 1000 characters?

Comment: @Halur, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, No, unfortunately still the same even with your suggestion.

Comment: @ClainDsilva, yes, all the file is uploaded. just checked.. I thought I was reaching the maximum upload size too but i have another file that has 300+ rows my code imports 270 rows of that into mysql.. it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Chris, no they have nothing in common at all... that is what I initially thought as well...

Comment: Why not build a mutiple insert ?

Comment: @Jackson, if you try to import the same file twice do the same rows get saved both times?

Comment: @aynber, SPOT ON.... I've switched to prepared statement and everything worked like a charm... I can post my code and accept that as the answer or you can post yours and I will accept yours.. either way, the prepared statement WORKS.. Thanks

Comment: Done! Thank goodness for prepared statements, they save me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around quoting issues, you want to use prepared statements with bind_param.

Procedural style:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, "INSERT INTO `myTable`(`column1`) VALUES(?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $line[0] );
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Object-oriented style:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `myTable`(`column1`) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $line[0]);

$stmt->execute();
```

Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), use `s` for strings, `i` for integers, and `d` for doubles/decimals.